# AlamoFire not being recognized on some pages but it is on others

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have imported AlamoFire into my project and for some reason it is now not being recognized on one of my pages. The project was working a few days ago now I'm getting the Apple Mach-O Linker error and I believe it is because I have this error after I clean and build: 
[image]

However on a separate page there is no error with importing AlamoFire. This makes no sense to me.
[image]

I have done `pod install` and it is showing it has installed and the project is using it. I don't understand why this was working a few days ago now it is not.

Comment: Is `BaseDataManager.swift` correctly listed as a file for your project, and in the correct Target ? Can you import it in another file ?

Comment: Where do I go to find that?

Comment: Select your file, on the left panel (Utilities), Show the File Inspector, check it's marked for your target (app). (Check that screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYuMx.jpg just at the end of the "red circles", there is a "Target MemberShip")

Comment: Most probably `Alamofire` is not added correctly to your project at all, but the compiler only shows you the error for the first problematic file and not for all. Did you add `Alamofire` under Embedded Binaries for your target and set up the correct framework search paths?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1lTc.png this is what the file inspector says about the BaseDataManager. It is checked for correct target

Comment: @DávidPásztor I did not add it anywhere other than doing the pod install but the app was working and is currently on TestFlight and been approved for external testing and now it just got this error so I would've thought it was all added correctly

Comment: So what did you change since it started not working that might have caused the issue?

Comment: I have no idea. When I try to build the project and get a linker error the error is: "Directory not found for option '-F/Users/Developer/Desktop/BagTracker/build/Release-iphoneos/AlamoFire'"

Comment: I've seen that maybe I need to delete the path to the framework but before I make any stupid decisions I want someone to confirm that this could be the solution. Should I delete the ones that have AlamoFire in them? https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH9gP.png

Comment: It could be some cache thing! Clean, Clean Build Folder, delete Derived Data folder, quit Xcode, run `pod deintegrate`, run `pod install`, open Xcode and try again.

Comment: You are a life saver @NiñoScript. That solved everything

Comment: I wasn't actually expecting it to solve everything, but that's great, I'll write it as an answer then :)

Comment: Haven't tried archiving it yet but I can at least build and get past the Mach-o linker error. Hopefully I don't run into the same stuff when trying to archive

Comment: Archiving doesn't use the cache, so no need to worry there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably some cache issue, those are somewhat common in Xcode.

Clean, Clean Build Folder, delete Derived Data folder, quit Xcode, run `pod deintegrate`, run `pod install`, open Xcode and try again.

One of those steps usually solves this kinds of problems.

Happy Coding!